# Why am I getting this compiler warning?

Tags: objective-c, ios, compiler-warnings

I'm getting a compiler warning when using the following code:

```
for(int i=0; i<[mutableTempArray count]; i++){
  //...
  [tempInfoDictionary setValue:i forKey:@"tag"];
  //...
}
```

The warning is:

> passing argument 1 of 'setValue:forKey:' makes pointer from integer without a cast

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Collections in Objective-C can only hold **objects**, so you'll need to wrap `i` in an `NSNumber` object.

`i` itself is a primitive type, not an object, so it can't be put inside a collection object.

The first argument to `setValue:forKey:` is expected to be of pointer type, which `i` itself clearly isn't.

I suggest using the `setObject:forKey:` method on an `NSDictionary` instead of `setValue:forKey:`, because it states your intentions better. You're not only storing a *value*, you're storing an ***object***

```
[tempInfoDictionary setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"tag"];
```

Comment: It's a little confusing at first what the difference is between `setValue:forKey:` and `setObject:forKey:`.  As @Jacob notes, one difference is that `setObject:forKey:` only accepts objects.  But that doesn't mean you can use `setValue:forKey:` to set non-object values in your `NSMutableDictionary`; `setValue:forKey:` is a method common to `NSObject` subclasses that is primarily used for setting properties by name. In the collection classes the behavior is a little more specific; for `NSMutableDictionary` it's a synonym for `setObject:forKey:`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to put an `int` into an object array, but it's expecting an `id` i.e. a pointer.  Try `[tempInfoDictionary setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i] forKey:@"tag"];`